# How to complete sql query to display whole month?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question that seems easy but i failed to solve it by myself

i have this mysql table with the statistics of a website visitors

```
+-----------------------------+
+ date        | visits        +
+-----------------------------+
+  2014-03-01 | 198           +
+  2014-03-02 | 259           +
+  2014-03-03 | 94            +                 
+-----------------------------+
```

i have this query

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date >= '2014-03-01' and date <= '2014-03-30';
```

My question is if i can complete the whole month with one sql query so i can get this output:

```
+-----------------------------+
+ date        | visits        +
+-----------------------------+
+  2014-03-01 | 198           +
+  2014-03-02 | 259           +
+  2014-03-03 | 94            +                 
+  2014-03-04 | 0             +                 
+  2014-03-05 | 0             +                 
+  2014-03-06 | 0             +
...             
+  2014-03-30 | 0             +                 
+-----------------------------+
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Not in a very smart way, but creating a temp table of the dates and then left joining would work.

Comment: Not related to your question, but in your code, <= '2014-03-30' should be < '2014-04-01' for two reasons.  You'll have to think about what those two reasons are.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by one sql query?
Here you are also using one single query.

"SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date >= '2014-03-01' and date <= '2014-03-30'"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Between clause. You can write that one like

"SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-30'".

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

SQL can't (easily) create rows where there is no data. That means if there are no rows for 2014-03-05, then you won't get a row, let alone one where the count is 0. The only real way to "create" such empty rows is to have another table with a list of the dates that you `LEFT JOIN` to. But this is awfully naff.

Secondly, you can fetch a whole months' worth easily with the following:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND DATE_ADD('2014-03-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```